# Curl working on localhost but not through AWS external service. Getting 403 Forbidden Request

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to do a simple curl request to the website "www.houzz.com".

```
$url="http://www.houzz.com/";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
```

The code worked perfectly on my localhost machine however now that I switched to AWS it does not seem to be working with my EC2 instance. The page now loads:

```
"403 Forbidden. Request forbidden by administrative rules."
```

It worked two times when I launched a new beanstalk application, however most of the times it did not making me think it had something to do with the IP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The remote website might be blocking your request based on it being from AWS?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I considered that, so is there any way around it? Would I have to just keep jumping IPs with new instances until I found one that worked? Or would it mean finding a non AWS host.

Comment: Assign an elastic IP to the instance so that it's static and then ask the houzz admin to whitelist your IP?